# Dynamic select box/multiselect box based on other field in pimcore

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

In the class definition, I have two select boxes, first select box has 5 items if I select any item from the first select box, the value of the second select box should get change. I am using pimcore v6.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make custom combobox(Select BOX) using EXT JS and onChange Event Get The data for another combobox then save those datas in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pimcore dynamic select types: https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Dynamic_Select_Types.html